# what is the most pythonic way to implement dotProduct?

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I am trying to implement dot product in Python using numpy arrays. So far, the code I am using works:

```
x = np.random.rand(5,5)
w = np.random.rand(5,1)
dot_product = np.zeros((5,1), dtype = np.dtype('O'))

for j in range(len(dot_product[:,0])):
     for i in range(len(dot_product[0,:])):
         sumt = 0
         for column in range(len(x[0,:])):
             temp_x = x[j,column]
             temp_plain = w[column,i]
             sumt += temp_x * temp_plain
         dot_product[j,i] = sumt
```

However, I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do it.

Of course, I know about the existance of `numpy.dot`, which will compute the dot product but I want to implement it myself, this is because I am working with encrypted data, so I can not use the common multiplication and addition.

The goal of the question is to know how to optimize the code, not to use an existing function.

Comment: IU think you need to subtract 1 to those ranges?

Comment: encrypted data? you're doing dot products on homomorphic encryption?

Comment: @Nullman, correct, I am using pySeal library to classify MNIST data using homomorphic encryption, to do so I have made a "custom" dot product method, but it takes too long, that's why I am trying to finding a way to optimize the loop.

Comment: `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1`

Comment: I think numpy is implemented in C? With regards to context, I don't see how reimplementing it in Python will be better performance-wise than just using `np.dot`.

Comment: Not able to repdoduce your example, getting an error @marisa

Comment: @TrebledJ the performance doesn't need to be better than `np.dot` it is enought it is better than the actual one

Comment: if you choose to stick to `numpy`, did you already try `np.einsum`?

Comment: `sumt += temp_x * temp_plain` thats 3 operations AND you are using up your quota on `sumt`. your best best would probably be to vectorize your operations, but im not even going to pretend i know how to do that

Comment: same @marisa `index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1`

Comment: @yatu, now it should be working!

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254475/how-do-i-move-away-from-the-for-loop-school-of-thought must be the key to a solution.

Comment: @Heike, the thing is that I am working with encrypted data and therefore I can not use the usual multiplication, because actually, x is encrypted data, not a numpy array of numbers.

Comment: i think you might have better luck with this question on crypto stack exchange, i did see a similar question [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6778/how-to-compute-the-dot-product-on-encrypted-values)

Comment: @Marisa: Yes, I just noticed. The use of numpy arrays in your question threw me off.

Comment: `res[i,k]=sum(w[i,j]*x[j,k]) for j in range)` => `(w[:,:,None]*x[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)` is the best dot without dot.

Comment: i really thing the point of this question is how do you reduce the number of mathematical operations, as each addition and multiplication is extremely slow, like **takes seconds** slow

Comment: The way to improve speed in numpy is to move iterations to compiled code.

Comment: With object dtype arrays, `np.dot` uses the multiply and add methods of the elements, Docs for `tensordot` illustrate this for strings

Answer (score 1):

```
def dot_prod(x,w):
   if not ( x.shape[1]==w.shape[0]):
       raise Exception( 'The number of columns of the first matrix  does not match the number of rows of the second matrix ')

   dot_product = np.zeros((x.shape[0], w.shape[1]), dtype=np.dtype('O'))
   for i1,a in enumerate(x):
      for i2,y in enumerate(w.T):
         dot_product[i1,i2]= np.sum(a*y)
   return dot_product
```

**Output:**

```
>x = np.random.rand(5,3)
>w = np.random.rand(3,2)
>dot_prod(x,w)
array([[1.0216453677132162, 1.0520242959212602],
       [0.7139675035454871, 0.7616075739263084],
       [0.9126062852861008, 0.9864445729083398],
       [0.42673040494581216, 0.4203998986679549],
       [0.9638211885773351, 1.0142282080627387]], dtype=object)

>x.dot(w)
array([[1.02164537, 1.0520243 ],
       [0.7139675 , 0.76160757],
       [0.91260629, 0.98644457],
       [0.4267304 , 0.4203999 ],
       [0.96382119, 1.01422821]])


>x = np.random.rand(5,3)
>w = np.random.rand(2,2)
>dot_prod(x,w)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/alperen/Projects/tmp.py", line 8, in dot_prod
    raise Exception( 'The number of columns of the first matrix  does not match the number of rows of the second matrix ')
Exception: The number of columns of the first matrix  does not match the number of rows of the second matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested list comp.

```
def vdot(a, b):
    return sum(a*b)

a = np.arange(25).reshape((5, 5))
b = np.arange(15).reshape((5, 3))

res = np.array([[vdot(a_row, b_col) for b_col in b.T] for a_row in a])

assert np.all(res == np.dot(a, b))
```

Comment: im pretty sure this wont even work, i dont think you can use `sum`. im pretty sure the only operations you have are add, neg and mul